# MouseClickEvent Counter multiplies on multiple clicks VS C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, onclicklistener

When playing with clickevents in visual studio i came accross this error:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Testcounter = 0;
        pictureBox1.MouseClick += myMouseClickEventFunction;
    }

    private void myMouseClickEventFunction(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = colors.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
        int y = colors.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;
        Testcounter++;
        var point = new Point(e.X - pictureBox1.Width/2, e.Y - pictureBox1.Height/2);
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            for (int u = 0; u < y; u++)
            {
                if (cirkles[i, u].Contains(point))
                {
                    changeIndex(i, u);
                }
            }
        }
        this.Refresh();
    }
```

The first time i click my picturebox the counters value is 1, the second time the value is 2, 3th time 3,... Does anyone has any idea why this happends? thnx

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH1Sq.png)
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr6jY.png)

Comment: Well, you DO register the mouseclick event again every time the user clicks... Try to only register it once during startup, or simply call the function from your existing listener.

Comment: Obviously, thank you for the insight on a rediculous question!

Answer (score 0):

Because by executing this

```
pictureBox1.MouseClick += myMouseClickEventFunction;
```

You're adding the handler one more time with each click. Which should mean, that if you click it once, you add it once and it executes once. But with the second click, you add it one more time, so this time it will execute two times and that's why your counter is increasing to 2. What you need is to move your click handler somewhere else and register it only one time, which means that the best place to move it should be in the initialization of the form. (In `public MainForm(){}` or whatever form you're using the code in)
P.S.: Sorry for the poor english, I hope you understood me.

Comment: Obviously, thank you for the insight on a rediculous question!

Comment: I'm not sure if that's irony, but if so - you'te the one asking, mate. If not, then no problem :D